# What does this coloring mean?

Tags: kittens-game

In the Kittens game, some of my resources and amount of resources are colored (see the screenshot). Does this have any meaning? Different colors seems unrelated, because the amount of iron and the amount of kittens are the same color, but I think they do not effect eachother.

Again, I do not want to look in the faq for spoiler reasons.

[image: My materials]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The orange color means you have filled 75% of your storage for that resource (so you should be ready to spend them, otherwise you'll be wasting time and/or food). Kittens are considered resource by the game so it will always be orange colored

catpower and science have different color but they do not have any real meaning, they're only there to help you differentiate themselves from other resources. Later on you'll find a ridiculous resource when hunting, that will have orange color AND glow

Answer (score 3):

*(Partial answer, so not complete (for now) and still looking for the answer what the coloring of the resource means).*

The orange resource amount is just (very close to) the maximum, I just discovered that. Furthermore, there also seems to be a wider range where the resource amount has a different  color then the orange, it's sort of salmon-colored. My amount of kittens was then 80% of the maximum. At 90% (9 out of 10 kittens) it was still salmon colored.

[image: Resources]

So orange resource amount means that it hit (or is very very close to) the maximum. Salmon colored resource amount means close to the maximum.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are the titles coloured? (I.e. 'Catpower' is orange and 'science' is blue.) Why?

Comment: Well, that is the remaining question. I tried to make that clear by the first *italic* part of the answer. So the colored amount is 'solved', the colored titles not (yet). I'm still waiting for someone to answer that, or until I discover it myself. Meanwhile, I've got more resources with a color, but I do not have a certain idea how this is related.

Comment: I understand that it is incomplete. Though my confusion probably stems from ignorance. Never even heard of this game until now

Comment: I also begin playing because of questions here. It's an awesome game (and addictive like hell...)